# How to format varchar with nanoseconds into date for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar field that looks like this:

```
08-Nov-17 04.01.34.123456789 PM
```

How can I convert this into a date that I can then use in my WHERE clause?  I cannot figure out how to use `TO_DATE`, specifically on the trailing  nanosecond string portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `to_date`.  You use `to_timestamp`  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) is your reference.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem.  I used:  `TO_TIMESTAMP(myField, 'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.FF PM')`